# Show a RTSP stream in html

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, rtsp

I want to show a stream of an IP camera in html website.IP camera send data with RTSP protocol. I used some codes like [html5 RTSP](https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player/wiki/HTML5-RTSP-Player) && Google WebRTC. But I feeled these codes can't receive and show RTSP streams and not worked for me. I tested some methods that uses VLC but I wan't to show stream without using VLC and I want to implement this program as client side program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple and good way to play RTSP directly in browser.  It is possible to do it on old Android devices, on some STB or with VLC plugin which is not a good way to go.

You will have to install media server that will convert your RTSP to something for browser.

It is possible to take ffmpeg that will convert your rtsp to hls and have a live video translation from camera, but if you want more feature like stream management or recording you can look at commercial options like Flussonic (I'm working on it) or Wowza.

You can also google something like  "streaming server" and look for RTSP and HLS/RTMP protocols in specification.

Comment: Convert RTSP to HLS is not a good solution for real-time IP camera stream, it delays streaming about 5 seconds or more.

Answer (score 0):

There has media source extensions(MSE) can support live h264 with very low latency(Chrome Firefox Safari below 1s). but there need a gateway to convert RTSP to fragmented MP4.

Comment: https://github.com/linkingvision/h5stream this link may help you test the performance of the MSE latency.